# How do I get which element is clicked first and which element is clicked second in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am trying to build a guessing game in JavaScript. I've made all numbers inside a div. The thing I want is when I click on one div, how can I compare the first one with the second one and display the result as right or wrong**

```js
// ?    number clicked logic
const numberClicked = document.querySelectorAll('.number')
numberClicked.forEach((number) => {
    number.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (number.textContent == "") {
            number.textContent = randomNumber()
            number.style.background = "orangered"
            let numberClickOne = e.target.textContent
            console.log("click " + numberClickOne);  
        }
    })
})


// ?    generates random number each time it is called
function randomNumber() {
    let randomDigit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1)
    return randomDigit
}
```

```html
<div class="number number1"></div>
                <div class="number number2"></div>
                <div class="number number3"></div>
                <div class="number number4"></div>
                <div class="number number5"></div>
                <div class="number number6"></div>
                <div class="number number7"></div>
                <div class="number number8"></div>
                <div class="number number9"></div>
                <div class="number number10"></div>
                <div class="number number11"></div>
                <div class="number number12"></div>
                <div class="number number13"></div>
                <div class="number number14"></div>
                <div class="number number15"></div>
                <div class="number number16"></div>
                <div class="number number17"></div>
                <div class="number number18"></div>
                <div class="number number19"></div>
                <div class="number number20"></div>
                <div class="number number21"></div>
                <div class="number number22"></div>
                <div class="number number23"></div>
                <div class="number number24"></div>
                <div class="number number25"></div>
```

Comment: I'd make an array that is initialized to [0, 0].

Then I'd have a counter that increments each time a number is clicked.

Then when the function is called I'd check to see if the counter is > 1.

If it's not, set the array[counter] to that number.

if it is, then two numbers have been clicked and you need to compare them.

Reset the counter to 0 and compare the numbers.

I'm sure there are a million other ways to do it though.

If you'd like me to post the code for this to make it clearer please let me know.

Comment: Yes can u give code to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer, I'm dynamically creating the number divs, just for simplicity. I'm adding that div's number to a data attribute.

I'm adding an event handler to the parent object of the number divs and checking if the clicked target includes the number class.

In my click handler, I just grab the data attribute number and check it against the randomly generated number.

I also updated your random function to accept an argument for the max that way you can easily control the max.

```js
function randomNumber(max) {
  let randomDigit = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1)
  return randomDigit
}

let numbers = document.querySelector(".numbers");

for (let x = 1; x <= 25; x++) {
  let number = document.createElement("div");
  number.classList.add("number");
  number.innerText = x
  number.setAttribute("data-number", x)
  numbers.appendChild(number)
}

numbers.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.className.includes("number")) {
    let rand = randomNumber(25)
    if(e.target.dataset.number == rand){
      console.log("GOOD!",rand);
   }
   else{console.log("WRONG! it was ",rand);}
  }
});
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="numbers"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's Your solution using Event Delegation
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="./index.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="number">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your javascript logic
index.js

```
document.querySelector(".number").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
//creating a random number
let randomDigit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1)
//storing selected number
let Selectednum=+e.originalTarget.innerText
// + to convert number from type string to number

//now checking with conditions if the if else
if(Selectednum===randomDigit){
    alert("hurrah! You won")
}
else{
    alert("Better Luck Next Time ")
}
})
```